# Limit of $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \frac{{n\choose k}}{n^k(k+3)}$ when $n\to\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits

What is $$ \lim_{n \to  \infty} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{{n\choose k}}{n^k(k+3)}\ ?$$ I know the way by integration and that the answer is $e-2$ but I am more interested in use of sandwich theorem which provides a maxima or a closed form to it. Expansions may also be useful.

Comment: Also that's not a sequence.

Comment: I fixed the limit display but it's unclear to me what the lower summation bound is supposed to be.  $k=1$ maybe?  Please update accordingly.

Comment: its n to infinity and sum is from 0 to n

Comment: For a closed form, you may remark that if $S_n$ is your sum, you have $S_n=\int_0^1 x^2(1+x/n)^ndx$, and putting $x=nu$ you get $S_n=n^3\int_0^{1/n}u^2(1+u)^n du$. Writing $u^2=(1+u)^2-2(1+u)+1$ and integrating gives you a closed form. But we have integrated...

Comment: For an upper bound, use the fact that $${n\choose k}\leqslant\frac{n^k}{k!}$$ hence the $n$th sum $S_n$ is such that $$S_n\leqslant\sum_{k=0}^n\frac1{k!(k+3)}<\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{k!(k+3)}$$ For a lower bound, fix some $N$ and note that, for every $n\geqslant N$, $$S_n\geqslant\sum_{k=0}^N\frac{{n\choose k}}{n^k(k+3)}$$ Now, the RHS has a finite number of terms whose limit is clear, hence $$\liminf S_n\geqslant\sum_{k=0}^N\frac1{k!(k+3)}$$ The lower bound holds for every $N$, qed.

Answer (score 3):

For $0\leq k\leq n$,
$$1-\frac{\binom{k}{2}}{n}\leq \prod_{j=1}^{k-1}\left(1-\frac{j}{n}\right)=\frac{k!}{n^k}\binom{n}{k}\leq 1$$
where the empty product is $1$.
Therefore
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!(k+3)}-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{\binom{k}{2}}{k!(k+3)}\leq \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{{n\choose k}}{n^k(k+3)}\leq \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!(k+3)} \tag{1}$$
Then by noting that $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\binom{k}{2}}{k!(k+3)}$ converges, it follows that the sequence $\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{{n\choose k}}{n^k(k+3)}$ is bounded and, by applying the [Squeeze Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) in (1), we have
$$\lim_{n \to  \infty} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{{n\choose k}}{n^k(k+3)}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!(k+3)}=e-2.$$

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> Besides the
>   ['sandwich' answer of $\texttt{@RobertZ}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2700026/85343),
>   the following answer provides an alternative approach:

\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to  \infty}\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{{n \choose k} \over n^{k}\pars{k + 3}} & =
\lim_{n \to  \infty}\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k}
\pars{1 \over n}^{k}\int_{0}^{1}t^{k + 2}\,\dd t =
\lim_{n \to  \infty}\int_{0}^{1}t^{2}\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k}
\pars{t \over n}^{k}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
\lim_{n \to  \infty}\int_{0}^{1}t^{2}\pars{1 + {t \over n}}^{n}\,\dd t =
\lim_{n \to  \infty}\bracks{n^{3}\int_{0}^{1/n}t^{2}\pars{1 + t}^{n}\,\dd t}
\end{align}

> The last integral can be evaluated by succesive integration by parts which decreases the $\ds{t^{2}\mbox{-exponent}}$ to $\ds{0}$.

Namely,
\begin{align}
&\lim_{n \to  \infty}\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{{n \choose k} \over n^{k}\pars{k + 3}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{n \to \infty}\braces{n^{3}\bracks{-2n^{3} + \pars{1 + 1/n}^{n}\pars{1 + n}\pars{2 + n + n^{2}} \over n^{3}\pars{1 + n}\pars{2 + n}\pars{3 + n}}} =
\bbx{\expo{} - 2}
\end{align}